# How does a for loop without contents before its first semi-colon work?

Tags: c

I've been coming across this sort of loops, they work as expected but I would love to understand how C compilers see these loops.`for(;i<10;i++){}
for(;a;a= a->next){}`

Comment: "how C compilers see these loops." do you want AST or something?

Comment: Nope, the two answers have answered my question though.

Answer (score 4):

`for (a; b; c) d;` is equivalent to the following:

```
{
  a;
  while (b)
  {
    d;
    c;
  }
}
```

So omitting the first part just omits `a`, i.e. the initialization statement. So the compiler sees it as equivalent to the following:

```
while (b)  
{
  d;
  c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop there are three phases that can be observed as:

`for(a;b;c) d;`

**A: Initial declarations**

This is assignments or declarations that are preformed at the beginning of the loop.

**B: Loop stipulation**

This is the stipulation that must be true to continue iteration.

**C: Iteration declaration**

This is declarations or assignments that will take place after each loop iteration.

**D: Loop body**

This is the body of the loop that is executed after the A and B but before C.

The order can be observed as:

```
A();

while(B) {
    D();
    C();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the `for` statement is the initialization statement. It simply initializes one of the  loop variables. It is normally omitted when its use would be duplicative, e.g.:

```
int i = 0;
...
for (; i < x; i++) { ... }
```

As you can see in that example, inclusion of `i = 0` would simply repeat the original initialization. You also commonly see the omission related to pointers, for the same reason, i.e.

```
char buf[] = "a quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
char *p = buf;
...
for (; *p; p++) { ... }
```

Here again, `p = buf` would be duplicative.